# Integral over quarter circle

Tags: definite-integrals, multiple-integral

It is given quarter circle in first quadrant $G=\left\{ \left(x,y\right) \in \mathbb R ^{2}: x\geq 0, y\geq 0, 9\leq x^{2}+y^{2}\leq 49 \right\} $
and $g(x,y)=x^2y^2+4y$.

Calculate integral over $G$  (use polar coordinates):
$\int_{G}^{} \!  g(x,y)d(x,y) \, $

Idea:

$x=rcos\theta $

$y=rsin\theta$

$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2} } \! \int_{3}^{7} \! r(r^2cos(\theta)^2 r^2 sin(\theta)^2+4rsin(\theta)) \, dr  \, d\theta $

Am I on the good way?

Comment: Wouldn't this be a quarter-annulus and not a quarter circle?

Comment: Yes, continue .use $\sin(2t)=2\sin(t)\cos(t)$

Comment: @AbdallahHammam Why? I dont have here $sin(2t)$ ?

Comment: @AnaMatijanovic You have $\sin^2(t)\cos^2(t)=\frac(\sin^2(2t)}{4}$

Answer (score 1):

Let continue your good start

$$I=\int_3^7r^5dr\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1-\cos(4\theta)}{8}d\theta$$

$$+4\int_3^7r^2dr\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin(\theta)d\theta$$

$$=\frac{\pi}{96}(7^6-3^6)+\frac{4}{3}(7^3-3^3)$$
Yes you can finish it.